# Can I use fewer than the recommended number of fasteners for exterior wall insulation?

Tags: walls, insulation, exterior

I'm insulating my exterior wall (built of perforated Porotherm blocks) using 40mm gutex wood-fibre boards.  The recommended application involves the use of an adhesive (allegedly very strong) and plastic fasteners / anchors. The insulation layer will be applied over the existing (cement-based) rendering.  The recommended number of fasteners for gutex boards is minimum 6 per square metre, which I find excessive.  Is there a good reason why I should use so many dowels (and bore so many holes into my wall) ?  Can it be avoided - especially given that the adhesive is very strong and is applied continuously rather than just in spots?

Comment: I've edited your question title to get to the heart of the matter. However, you're basically asking us to advise going against manufacturer specifications and exposing you to more risk of failure. Not many folks have good reason to do that.

Comment: @Levente - your material might warp could be one of the reasons they Recommend to do this - I would suggest to follow their recommendation. Cheaper to do it right the first time than it is to do it right the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Your material might warp could be one of the reasons they recommend to do this - I would suggest to follow their recommendation.

While any one can ignore a manufacturers recommendation given the manufacturer has studied their product and engineered out issues with their product and tested it - I mean what could they possibly know about their own product.. right?

That said here is my recommendation:

Cheaper to do it right the first time than it is to do it right the second time.